# What is the largest capacity power bank on the market?

Tags: power-bank

I am looking for a very large power bank, as I am very bad about charging my devices. Ideally the power bank I am looking for is as follows-

- Under $200
- Over 30,000 mAh
- Flat and small so that it can be mounted in a backpack
- Weighs less than 10 lbs (or 4.5 kg)
- Not jagged: this has to be carried around, so I need it to not hurt me

I have had a hard time finding reliable sellers for such a thing, so make sure the battery you are looking at isn't a scam.

- I am willing to give up on the weight if that makes this impossible.
- I am also willing to go over budget but not to a massive degree. ~$50

It seems strange that I essentially want a car battery for my laptop, but I would find a thing to be very useful.

Comment: Have you considered attaching solor panels to your devices?

Comment: @TheWob-buffet, 30000 mAh corresponds to a rather large solar panel.

Comment: @mark i mean get one good them good enough per device so they dont run out of battery during the day, assuming he doesnt live in a cave.

Comment: @Mark, it's about power not capacity. Assuming a ~90 W charger for the laptop, a 200 Wp panel should be plenty and the first search result has half the weight the asker envisages. http://www.amazon.com/Go-Power-GP-FLEX-200-Crystalline-Controller/dp/B00HSM39TW Just saying.

Comment: @Nemo, 200W corresponds to 40A at the 5V typical of a power bank.  Now, in practice, you're only going to get about half of that due to poor solar angles or shade, so the twelve square feet of solar panel you've linked to will take about two hours to equal a 30 Ah power bank.  Thanks for proving my point.

Comment: @Mark are you assuming that the asker needs to draw all power from the power bank in less than 2 hours? I see no such specification in the question.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Portable-Charger-PowerPack-Ultra-High-Density/dp/B01BLXY3B6/ref=sr_1_74?ie=UTF8&qid=1485835046&sr=8-74&keywords=usb+power+bank&refinements=p_72%3A2661618011

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking in to account your desire to charge your laptop, the largest battery I could find within your budget and from what appears to be a reputable seller would be the [BiXPower BP-160](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0087HW5YM).

- Slightly over $200 at $209+shipping.
- Capacity of 153Wh, equivalent to 42,500mAh@3.6V.  This is likely 2-3x the capacity of your laptop's internal battery.
- Not overly small (11"x6"x1.25"), but it is flat and should fit in the bottom of most backpacks.
- Weighs just under 3lbs.
- Outputs either 12V or 19V.  Most laptops use 19V or close enough, and most netbooks use 12V.  It also includes a selection of adapter tips which should allow it to work with just about any laptop.
  Also has a USB port for charging mobile devices.
- The seller has plenty of positive reviews on both this product and as a seller on Amazon.  They also answer product questions.

They also offer even larger packs (which they don't appear to sell on Amazon) above your budget, like the [BP-220](http://www.bixpower.com/Bat-BP220-p/bat-bp220.htm) (223 watt-hours, $290) and the [CP-300K](http://www.bixpower.com/Bat-CP300K-p/bat-cp300xdd90.htm) (300 watt-hours, $400).

Answer (score 3):

I use an **EasyAcc PB12000** (12,000 mAh) to power my Raspberry Pi.  Given how long the Pi will run on a single charge, it does appear to reach its claimed capacity.

EasyAcc doesn't appear to sell that model any longer, but a pair of [these 15000 mAh batteries](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00M8UFTQA) should meet your criteria:

- Total capacity: 30,000 mAh
- Total cost: $54
- Total weight: 1.25 pounds
- Strap a pair of them to some sort of stiff backing, and you've got your flat form factor.

Comment: Fair warning: Stack Exchange rewrites Amazon affiliate links to its own - you won't be getting any clickthrough credit for that :) Good answer, though.

Comment: I don't think this type of device is what they're wanting.  The last line says they're wanting to be able to charge a laptop with it.

Comment: Probably still cheaper to find a dc dc boost board than to buy a niche product which can already output the voltage they need. Probably those expensive products do much the same internally, so efficiency doesn't need to be much worse.